# Sort unsorted Dictionary or Array of dictionaries with dynamic keys

Tags: swift, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary with dynamic keys like below.

```
  {
    5 : {
    value : 1000,
    desp : "No Desp"
    },
    1 : {
    value : 1000,
    desp : "No Desp"
    },
    2 : {
    value : 1000,
    desp : "No Desp"
    }
}
```

I want to sort this dictionary like below: In a swift dictionary sorted based on the key ascending order.

```
 {

    1 : {
    value : 1000,
    desp : "No Desp"
    },
    2 : {
    value : 1000,
    desp : "No Desp"
    }},

    5 : {
    value : 1000,
    desp : "No Desp"
    }


]
```

Comment: As has been discussed many, many times, a dictionary can't be sorted. It's an unordered collection.

Comment: I agree. but my api provides me the data in such pattern json, so I am looking for a workaround

Comment: The workaround is to put the key-value pairs into an array and sort that.

Comment: @Zord Sorry but your last statement isn't clear. There is no need for anyone to care about the order of a dictionary. That's not to say that you can't get an array of keys from the dictionary and then sort that array so you can access the values in a specific order, but that's very different from worrying about trying to sort an unordered collection.

Comment: You should redo you question to clearly explain why you think you need to sort the dictionary. What is your actual goal?

Comment: Yea Maddy, Thats why I didnt put any swift code like let dict:Dictionary be something and so on.. I have just given a json dictionary and I want some output to be formed like the sample in any code. I had same thought of  sorting dict.keys.sorted and create another dictionary from the index of sorted keys array. But I am checking If  I can get best solution. Always remember, the person who posts a question like this is not that dumb that he didn't do basic R&D :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of dictionary can not be sorted, so you need to use an **array** to do so.

```
let dict = [1:[value : 1000, desp : "No Desp"], 2: [value : 1000, desp : "No Desp"],3: [value : 1000, desp : "No Desp"]]

dict.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })  //do this to sort it by key
```

The result data type is a array of [Int,[String:Int, String:String]].

Comment: You are a real tech mechanic. I like your work attitude... Yes that's a pretty neat solution for something impossible.

Comment: @Zord `let sorted = dict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }`

Comment: This answer hardcodes an array of tuples. That's quite different from a dictionary obtained from JSON from some API.

Comment: Yes But I am fine to do few enumerations to carry them as tuples coz they got fewer counts not more than 5. The whole point of me posting this question is to find a better solution to reduce those enumerations

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this previously,

```
let unsortedDict = Dictioanary<String,Any>

let sortedKeys  = unsortedDict.keys.sorted

var sortedDict = NSMutableDictionary ()

for key in sortedKeys {
let node = unsortedDict[key]
sortedDict.setValue(node,forKey:key)
}
```

wondering any better way than this